# How to submit radio box values without a form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying two json files data in two tables. I am able to `console.log()` the value of each row selected. I made a submit button, but I am not sure how to get those **two** values to submit it. Does someone could help me to understand how to do that ?

**Below are my two tables**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Choose your outbound</h1>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                    <th>Arrival</th>
                    <th>Economy class</th>
                    <th>Business class</th>
                    <th>First class</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="outbound in outbounds" ng-class="{active : isSelected(outbound)}" ng-click="setMaster(outbound)">          
                    <td>{{ outbound.departure }}h</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.arrival }}h</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.ecoPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.businessPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.firstPrice }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioOutbound">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Choose your inbound</h1>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                    <th>Arrival</th>
                    <th>Economy class</th>
                    <th>Business class</th>
                    <th>First class</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="inbound in inbounds" ng-class="{active : isSelected(inbound)}" ng-click="setMaster(inbound)">  
                    <td>{{ inbound.departure }}h</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.arrival }}h</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.ecoPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.businessPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.firstPrice }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="radioInbound">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Below is my AngularJS**

```
// Inbound
$scope.isSelected = function(inbound) {
    return $scope.selected === inbound;
}

$scope.setMaster = function(inbound) {
    $scope.selected = inbound;
    console.log($scope.selected);
}

// Outbound
$scope.isSelected = function(outbound) {
    return $scope.selected === outbound;
}

$scope.setMaster = function(outbound) {
    $scope.selected = outbound;
    console.log($scope.selected);
}

// Submit
$scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.selected);
}
```

Comment: Create `$scope.submit()` function in your controller. Send the data you log into console to the method you want.

Comment: Also there is no need for two `$scope.isSelected()` functions, you may leave one.

Comment: @Georgy I updated my code with your solution. The only problem I have now is that I only have the value of the last radio box selected. How to get the values of the two radio box?

Comment: Well, you can pass a second argument `type` for `inbound` and `outbound` and make `$scope.selected` an object `{}`. Then you can rewrite `$scope.setMaster(type, data)` to `$scope.selected[type] = data;`, where `data` would equal to `inbound` or `outbound` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a plunker that I believe demonstrates your desired goal. My understanding from your code was:

- You wanted either the radio button or the row clicked to select the item. The inbound and outbound items were each seperate sections, and only one radio in each should be selected.
- All data should be returned back to the controller, once selected. This will send it all back in one objected, broken down by the model.

Within $scope.submit, you will find the selected option for inbound on formData.radioOutbound, and on formData.radioOutbound for the outbound item.

https://plnkr.co/edit/iwHi5NEDJSahG0JJ31ih?p=preview

JS
      // Submit
      $scope.submit = function(formData) {
          console.log(formData);
      }

```
  $scope.formData = {
    radioOutbound: '',
    radioInbound: ''
  };

  $scope.outbounds = [
      {
        departure: 'today',
        arrival: 'tomorrow',
        ecoPrice: 100,
        businessPrice: 200,
        firstPrice: 300
      },
      {
        departure: 'tomorrow',
        arrival: 'next day',
        ecoPrice: 100,
        businessPrice: 200,
        firstPrice: 300
      }
    ]

    $scope.inbounds = [
      {
        departure: 'today',
        arrival: 'tomorrow',
        ecoPrice: 100,
        businessPrice: 200,
        firstPrice: 300
      },
      {
        departure: 'tomorrow',
        arrival: 'next day',
        ecoPrice: 100,
        businessPrice: 200,
        firstPrice: 300
      }
    ]
```

HTML

```
 <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Choose your outbound</h1>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                    <th>Arrival</th>
                    <th>Economy class</th>
                    <th>Business class</th>
                    <th>First class</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="outbound in outbounds"
                    ng-class="{'success' : formData.radioOutbound == this.outbound}"
                    ng-click="formData.radioOutbound = this.outbound">

                    <td>{{ outbound.departure }}h</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.arrival }}</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.ecoPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.businessPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ outbound.firstPrice }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" ng-value="outbound" ng-model="formData.radioOutbound">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>Choose your inbound</h1>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                    <th>Arrival</th>
                    <th>Economy class</th>
                    <th>Business class</th>
                    <th>First class</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="inbound in inbounds"
                    ng-class="{'success' : formData.radioInbound == this.inbound}"
                    ng-click="formData.radioInbound = this.inbound">  
                    <td>{{ inbound.departure }}h</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.arrival }}h</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.ecoPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.businessPrice }}</td>
                    <td>{{ inbound.firstPrice }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" ng-value="inbound" ng-model="formData.radioInbound">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="submit(formData)">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thats exactly that thanks! Could you explain me more about the formData ?

Comment: formData was just an object I decided to use as the object to hold the data, you could rename it to something else if you wanted. Because of scoping (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), a primitive model will not exist on the parent. By initially setting it in the controller, when we change the values within ng-repeat (child scope), we are able to change the values and then access it in the parent scope. I see tons of questions that in some manner have a scope issue, I always recommend people read this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 1):

add `ng-model` to radio button

```
<td>
   <input type="radio" name="radioOutbound" ng-model="radio_value1">
</td>
```

and for the second one also

```
<td>
   <input type="radio" name="radioInbound" ng-model="radio_value2">
</td>
```

in the submit function you can pass the two values

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="submit(radio_value1, radio_value2)" >Submit</button>
```

in the controller

```
$scope.submit = function(val1, val2){
  console.log(val1, val2);
}
```

if you dont want to pass values in the function then values will be in `$scope.radio_value1` and `$scope.radio_value2`

Comment: Thanks for sharing. With your solution, I got undefined variables in the console...

Comment: The variables were undefined here due to the isolated scope of ng-repeat. You should always use a "." in this, such as formData.something, such as in the example in my post. Since the submit button was outside of the ng-repeat scope, radio_value1 and radio_value2 did not exist at submission.